# If login button is present, login - Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

This is login button. So if it is present, it should login. If not, should go on code.

```
<button class="md-button ng-scope 
    md-ink-ripple layout-align-xs-start-start" 
    type="button" ng-transclude="" data-menu-item="login" ng-click="vm.login()" 
    ng-if="!vm.isAuthenticated()" layout-align-xs="start start" 
    aria-label="person_outline global.menu.account.login">
       <md-icon class="ng-scope material-icons">person_outline</md-icon>
       <label translate="" class="ng-scope">Giriş</label>
       <div class="md-ripple-container"></div>
</button>
```

I tried

```
describe('Product dashboard module', function () {
        console.log('Product Dashboard Test starting');
        var dashboardPageObject = new DashboardPageObject();
        beforeEach(function () {
           var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
           browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('ng-click="vm.login()"')).then(function () {
           console.log('-Loging in');
           //here will be login jobs      
        })
 })
```

but

```
 Failed: element(...).then is not a function
```

I change to this

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element.all(by.cssContainingText('ng-click="vm.login()"'))
.then(function () {
```

error is:

```
 Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

I tried lots of things.

Answer (score 1):

The error `Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` is because in your `EC.visibilityOf()` method you are trying to pass `element.all()` which is an array. Buy EC will accept only `ElementFinder` and not `ElementArrayFinder`.

So if you want to perform certain operation only if the element available have a look at below example.

```
beforEach(function(){
  element(by.css('button.layout-align-xs-start-start')).isPresent().then(function(isElementDisplayed){
     if(isElementDisplayed){
        //perform login operation;
      }
   })
})
```

Comment: Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"

Comment: can you add `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` at the begining of beforeEach() and also you need to navigate to the respective url using `browser.get()` method.

Comment: InvalidElementStateError: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'ng-click="vm.login()"' is not a valid selector. maybe because there is no login button because already logged in?

Comment: the locator that you are using is wrong. I have updated it in my answer

Comment: @mark the reason it is showing "window.angular is undefined. This could be either because this is a non-angular page" error is you are not loading a page to execute the protractor code. try browser.get(typeYourUrlHere)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand your **If not, should go on code.** in your question. I have tried the below code, edit the else part as per your wish

```
var loginBtn = elemeent(by.buttonText('Login'));
loginBtn.isDisplayed().then(function (bool) {
   if (bool) {
       loginBtn.click();
   } else {
       // your logic goes here
   }
});
```

Comment: it is beforeeach so, it should go to it

Comment: if i am not wrong, you want to check for the login button, and if it is not there you want to execute the beforeEach function(). I am not sure whether it is possible. But you can use the above code in your beforeEach() and put the other logics you want to achieve inside the else block(inside the beforeEach())

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, you are missing 2 closing parenthesis on your `browser.wait()` call... Also your locator is incorrect, when accessing an attribute other than `class`, you need to use square brackets.

`browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.login()"]'))))`

And since Protractor is asynchronous you don't need a `.then()` after `browser.wait()`